# Packet capture not receiving data sent directly to IP address

Tags: c#, java, android, sockets

I am building a win7 program in C# that acts as a packet sniffer that searches for a specific packet and upon receiving it performs traceroute on the packets source. Here's how capture looks, it captures and results using wireshark are the same.

```
//Start capture
                startStop.Text = "Stop";

                capture = true;

                socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);

                info.Text = "Capturing on: " + ifaces.SelectedItem.ToString();
                socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ifs[ifaces.SelectedIndex], 0));

                socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);

                byte[] byTrue = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
                byte[] byOut = new byte[4];

                socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byTrue, byOut);

                socket.BeginReceive(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
```

The program that sends a specific packet is an android app that sends data to an IP address.

```
try{
            string server="http://32.32.32.32/"
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(server);
            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity("TRACERT"));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

Problem is that it times out on the execute method. Server is external IP of my PC (changed here). What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you try to send data from a client to a packet sniffer.

Main players of a TCP connection are the Server and the Client. The Server is waiting for connection requests from a client. The client initates the connection and often sends then a request.

A packet sniffer is just a bystander, listening to the communication of the client and the server.

In your description I can't find any information about a server, so I assume there is none. As there is no server, the connection can not be established and the client gets the timeout.

I don't know the exact idea you try to implement, but maybe you don't need a sniffer but a server. But if you need to implement a sniffer you should run a (web)server software on your Computer that accepts the connection attempt from your client.

Comment: I have XAMPP Apache server established. It works when I use internal IP and send from within the same Wifi. With external it does not.

Comment: @hubert I assume with internal and external addresses you mean the address your internet router uses on the WAN side (external) and the address you use from the private IP Range behind the Router (internal). Do you have a port forwarding configured in the router to forward the port 80 to your computer? Can you access your webserver from the outside (with a normal browser, maybe from your mobile device)?